# Maven - Is it possible to specify mirror in pom.xml?

Tags: maven, maven-2

Is it possible to specify mirror in pom.xml ?
For example I am want to make one my own repo like central repo. And I want disable requests to the central repo and make all requests to my own repo.
Is it possible to disable default central repo in Maven?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the [pom it's not possible to define mirror entries](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-model/maven.html) furthermore it would be bad practice if definition of mirrors were possible (which is not the case). Similar for [repositories definition in pom's](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/) (which are possible, but considered bad practice).

Best solution for such kind of thing is to install a [repository manager](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) which acts like a "own central repository."

Answer (score 16):

Mirror can't be in the pom.xml. but it can be put add to your project's files.

When using maven 3.3.1+, you can use the core extension [project-settings-extension](https://github.com/gzm55/project-settings-maven-extension#example) to load the project settings, and put project specific mirrors into `${basedir}/.mvn/settings.xml` in your project.

in `${basedir}/.mvn/extensions.xml`

```
    <extensions xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/EXTENSIONS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/EXTENSIONS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/core-extensions-1.0.0.xsd">
      <extension>
        <groupId>com.github.gzm55.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-settings-extension</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.5</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
```

in `${basedir}/.mvn/settings.xml`

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>id</id>
      <url>https://url-for-this-project/</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
</settings>
```

Comment: If the project has multiple modules, do you need that in each module, or will it work in just the root module?  That is, if I have pom.xml in a, a/b, a/b/c, a/b/d, a/d, a/d/e and a/d/f and each has the pom from the parent directory as it's parent pom (except for a, obviously), can I just create a/.mvn?

Comment: from maven 3.3.1, each invoke of maven must set property [`maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory`](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/15c647182af102b0adda6fb09e97c709c4c8a474/maven-embedder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli.java#L330), and this property is override by env `MAVEN_BASEDIR` or  auto [calculated](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/15c647182af102b0adda6fb09e97c709c4c8a474/apache-maven/src/bin/mvn#L122) recursively upward (like the `.git` dir) from the based dir detected via `-f pom-file` options or `pwd`.

Comment: In your case, just create `a/.mvn`, then the commands `mvn`, `mvn -pl b` and `mvn -f b/c/pom.xml` will all use 'a/.mvn'.

Comment: This worked for me like a charm - thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

That wouldn't make sense. POM files are not just to build projects, they are also uploaded to shared repositories. Now imagine that your POM ends up on Maven Central. What should happen when I add your project as dependency to one of my projects?

A better solution is to use a [Maven proxy server](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html).

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness. You won't get such kind of pom into central cause it will be rejected based on quality checks which exists on the path to central.

Comment: Well, I can think of several reasons why it might make sense. For example... the project references dependencies that name "joes-dead-repo" for indirect dependencies. You can't change those dependencies, but you might be able to use <mirror> to make mvn look to "my-live-repo".  In other words, deal with someone else's mess.  Settings.xml makes more sense...

Comment: @SteventheEasilyAmused It doesn't make sense to put that into the POM. `settings.xml` and running your own proxy/mirror is the correct solution.

Comment: A settings.xml is not provided to other consumers - so they can't get working builds without it whereas a published pom (with a mirror or equivalency type declaration) would be consumable. But NOT ideal.

Comment: Make sense, not best practice, but if you use computer in home and in company network, and the company force you to use a mirror because of proxy and internet block (which makes me so upset and limited as developer that motivates me to move of company, but is not the question). Is best to put on a per project basis, then change settings.xml every time your laptop is moved.

Comment: Thanks @AaronDigulla, I going to try that.

Comment: It makes sense in the case where the product is internal to your company and never intended to be published to Maven Central.  Otherwise, everyone in your company has to update their settings.xml.

Comment: @TroyDaniels I've worked at several companies and never encountered a case where we couldn't use the same settings.xml for every developer. Yes, you have to set that up once, but you also have to install Maven, so I don't see your point.