# How to prevent Maven to download artifacts from private nexus without touching the settings.xml in m2?

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I have a simple Maven project and I like it not to go and try to download from our private company nexus. Also I don't and can't make changes to the local m2 settings.xml file.

This is what my pom.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.stockui.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>stockclient-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>stock-ui</artifactId>

    <groupId>com.stockui</groupId>

    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>StockUIapplication</name>
    <description>StockUIapplication</description>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.stockui.parent</groupId>
            <artifactId>stockclient-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
            <version>21.0.1</version>

        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

I was reading that this section should prevent it but is doesn't work:

```
 <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Anyway, it keeps failing like this where xxxxx.com is our company nexus:

```
INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< com.stockui:stock-ui >------------------------
[INFO] Building StockUIapplication 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from nexus-public: https://xxxxx.com/nexus/repository/public/org/openjfx/javafx/21.0.1/javafx-21.0.1.jar
Downloading from releases: https://xxxxx.com/nexus/repository/releases/org/openjfx/javafx/21.0.1/javafx-21.0.1.jar
Downloading from perso-tmp-hack: https://xxxxx.com/nexus/repository/perso-tmp-hack/org/openjfx/javafx/21.0.1/javafx-21.0.1.jar
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx/21.0.1/javafx-21.0.1.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.000 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-02-05T08:01:50+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project stock-ui: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.stockui:stock-ui:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.openjfx:javafx:jar:21.0.1 in nexus-public (https://xxxxx.com/nexus/repository/public/) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

### Update

I tried to add repositories but still it go to the main m2 settings.xml.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49781683/916225 this might help.

Comment: thanks but i dont want to install proxy server on my pc just for maven ..

Comment: If you bypass the company nexus locally it would break the build for others e.g. on the build server etc.

Comment: Can you add the `mirror` parts of your `settings.xml`

Comment: Btw Maven 4 will support project specific `settings.xml` https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5659. This could help to reset the mirror settings in a project local configuration.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you really want to modify a `settings.xml` file but due to some kind of restrictions/security concerns adopted in your organization you're not allowed to do so.
In this case probably the simplest approach would be creating your own `settings.xml` with all the required nexus definitions and running maven like this:

```java
mvn -s /path/to/your/custom/settings.xml clean install
```

For convenience you might want to create an alias for this command or something, but in a nutshell `-s` option comes to the rescue here

Comment: You could also add a `.mvn/maven.config` and overwrite the settings location with `--settings .mvn/settings.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to set up the repository configurations directly within your `pom.xml` file. This approach ensures that the configuration is specific to the project and doesn't necessitate modifications to the overarching Maven settings.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: i added this to the pom.xml , but still it gos to the m2 settings.xml 
see updated answer

Comment: Note that the question has been updated with this change in a way that is not clear to readers, and it appears to invalidate this answer. If you wish you can roll back to the earlier version of the question, perhaps adding the full `pom.xml` in a question update section.

Answer (score 0):

The log shows that maven also check the `repo.maven.apache.org` but the missing artifact isn't available from this repository. Not only from the company nexus. So the problem isn't that maven requests the company nexus. The concrete JAR artifact `org.openjfx:javafx-21.0.1` doesn't exist. There is only a `pom` available: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx/21.0.1/

Comment: tnx , but i dont want it to go to the company nexus at all, when it find the artifact and when it donst